# Wordpress Pagination Not Working - Always Showing First Pages Content

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I am working on a website where I have a blog but I also have a custom post type to allow me to drop in some videos.

I would like to use pagination so that if there are more then 9 videos displayed, then pagination occurs.

The first part of this works. The videos are indeed limited to 9 per page and the pagination correctly shows up at the bottom.

However when I click on the link for the second page, even though the URL changes, the first pages videos are displayed.

For my 'normal' blog posts, pagination is working exactly as intended.

This is the current code that I am using for my custom post type:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts('post_type=videos&posts_per_page=9&paged=$paged'); ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Why your current code fails

Your always getting the content of the first page, because the [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) of parameters passed to `query_posts` being encapsulated in [single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) prevents variables (as well as escape sequences for special characters other than `$`) to be expanded.

`query_posts("post_type=videos&posts_per_page=9&paged=$paged");` *would* take care of that problem.

`query_posts('post_type=videos&posts_per_page=9&paged='.$paged);` *would* also.

And finally, passing an array of mixed arguments instead of a URL-query-style string *would* as well.

That being said though, [*you should not use query_posts at all*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts):

### How it should be done

As per your comment, you attempted to use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).
That is a very useful function indeed, but not the correct way to go if you want to use a [WordPress-Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) thereafter.
[`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) returns an array of post objects - the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object's `posts` property. But only that one property, without all the other goodies and methods, that [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) provides.

Hence, to go with your above code snippet, do something along the lines of this:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'videos',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $your_query->have_posts() ) {
        /* The Loop */
        while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) {
            $your_query->the_post();
            // do something
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, no posts found.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that, interesting reading.  However please could you provide the alternative using the get_posts() method.

Is it as simple as:

<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; get_posts("post_type=videos&posts_per_page=9&paged=$paged"); ?>

That isn't actually working for me but that might be because of code elsewhere?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time out to show me how to use this.  I really appreciate it.