# Need help with pagination

Tags: php, customization, templates, pagination

I have a problem figuring out the pagination.
Using the information i found in this [Wordpress Pagination Not Working - Always Showing First Pages Content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105977/wordpress-pagination-not-working-always-showing-first-pages-content) thread, i've managed to set up pagination on my page. The code looks like this:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'cat' => 6,
);
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $your_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="blog-masonry" class="row">
    <?php while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) {
        $your_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    }
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, no posts found.';
}
?>
```

The problem is the only way i can access the pages is by typing e.g. /page/2 in browser. How do i actually display the pagination (< 1 2 3 >)?

Sorry if the question is dumb, i'm a total newbie.

SOLUTION (as suggested by Vishit): add pagination after the loop

```
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
             echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( 
             get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'prev_text'          => __('Prev'),
            'next_text'          => __('Next'),
            'total' => $your_query->max_num_pages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args_blog = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' =>  get_option('posts_per_page ')
                );
                $query_blog = new WP_Query( $args_blog );
                if($query_blog->have_posts()) : while($query_blog->have_posts()) : $query_blog->the_post();

                 $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                 echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'prev_text'          => __('Prev'),
                'next_text'          => __('Next'),
                'total' => $query_blog->max_num_pages
            ) );
```

Comment: what is that? a dump of code is not a good answer. What does the code do and why?, what was the original problem the code solves?